# Months on x-axis instead of number

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, ggplotly, geom-text

I'm want to convert the numbers in the x-axis into months and I succeeded somehow but I want months to arrange in chronological order instead of alphabetical order.

I used the following code:

```
temp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month.abb[MoSold], fill = SalePrice)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = number) +
  xlab("Month") +
  theme_bw()
```

the above code is producing following graph [months in alphabetical order.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8PRC.png)

Instead, I want the graph to look like with name instead of the number [graph with chronological order without month name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioY9h.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`month.abb[]` produces characters, which don't have an inherent order to them in R aside from alphabetical, which is how ggplot displays them.

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(
  months = month.abb[1:10],
  num = 1:10),
  aes(months, num)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

To see them in the expected order, there are at least 3 options:

1. convert the `month.abb` to the `factor` data type, which can have a specified order.

   ## Convert months to factors using `forcats` package

   ggplot(data = data.frame(
   months = forcats::fct_reorder(month.abb[1:10], 1:10),
   num = 1:10),
   aes(months, num)) +
   geom_col()

   ## Convert months to factors using base R

   ggplot(data = data.frame(
   months = factor(1:10, labels = month.abb[1:10]),
   num = 1:10),
   aes(months, num)) +
   geom_col()

[image]

2. Or you might alternately use a numerical axis, with custom labels reflecting what you want:

   ggplot(data = data.frame(
   month_num = 1:10,
   num = 1:10),
   aes(month_num, num)) +
   geom_col() +
   scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) month.abb[x])
3. Or perhaps easiest of all, you might use a Date or POSIXct data type.

   ggplot(data = data.frame(
   month = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-10-01"), by = "month"),
   num = 1:10),
   aes(month, num)) +
   geom_col() +
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",
   minor_breaks = NULL, date_labels = "%b")
   [image]